# How can I generate random numbers in Avalanche?

Tags: chainlink, avax

I believe ChainLink VRF is not enabled in Avalanche. Is there any way to generate a secure random number there? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as of now Chainlink VRF is only accessible on ETH, BSC and some other testnets, but you can use [`Oraichain VRF`](https://blog.orai.io/oraichain-vrf-2-0-the-worlds-first-fully-on-chain-vrf-for-avalanche-network-df685e03bd94), accessible on AVAX, Fantom and other EVMs.

[Oraichain Docs](https://docs.orai.io/)

It works pretty similarly to Chainlink's VRF.